# 'Hello everyone' Vs. 'Hello everybody' Vs. 'Hello all'

Tags: word-choice

In the specific context of self-presentation in front of the audience, what's the politest or most natural way to approach the whole audience and begin the self-representation?

I think about three choices:

> "Hello **everyone**. My name is Leonardo..."

or

> "Hello **everybody**. My name is Leonardo..."

or

> "Hello **all**. My name is Leonardo..."

N.b. instead of 'hello' I may use the phrases "Good morning" or "Good evening" or "Good afternoon". If it matters for the answer, please let me know.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

From [**Learner's Dictionary**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/everybody-or-everyone):

> **Everybody vs Everyone**
>
> Both of these words mean "every person," and in dictionaries, the meaning of everyone is often given as everybody, and vice versa.
>
> However, it's worth mentioning that many people think everybody is a little more casual (more informal) than everyone. Also, everybody is used more often than everyone in spoken language, which makes sense if it's more informal. Having said this, it's absolutely fine to use either one. You have a choice.

Comment: The reference you provided contradicts your answer. The answer provided at "Ask an Editor" from the M-WD said no real difference. The distinctions you answer suggests were effectively some comments added by random strangers. :(  I will go what dictionaries say: no difference in meaning.

Comment: @RossMurray if you see answer by **Rodrigo_Roa_Duterte**, that matches.

Comment: What reason does anyone have to place any credibility in his opinion? Who is he? To me, he appears to be just some random individual on the internet, like you or me, mouthing off and saying he disagrees with the person employed by M-WD to answer questions. That is not a "reference". It means nothing!

Comment: ok! that is something I agreed to.. Ill remove the reference. What else do you have to say about the answer?

Comment: As I said above, "I will go what dictionaries say: no difference in meaning."

Comment: Ok! So should I delete this answer?

Comment: I do not know. I think you should ask to chat with a moderator, but I don't know how to start that. I acknowledge you are new here. I find it encouraging that you made an effort to include a reference in your answer. That's good. Unfortunately, the reference you chose this time was not credible and that's why I objected. PLEASE, keep trying and keep coming back! :-)

Comment: Thanks! May be I had wrong belief about that. Rather I would update the answer.

Comment: "Everyone" and "everybody" have no difference. But Quirk et al. (1985) say the former is more elegant than the latter. But that book is 30 years old now.

Comment: @rahulgawale  Your edits seem to have fixed the problem.  Your answer is fine as it is.  However I agree with Ross Murray that Rodrigo_Roa_Duterte's comment is just his opinion, and should be regarded as such.